# Converting SQL query for use with PHP form (issue with variables)

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query that looks like:

```
SET @fromyear = 1980;
SET @toyear = 1989;


SET @rank = 0;

SELECT test.Rank, test.Artist, test.Nominations

FROM(


SELECT 
@rank:=@rank+1 as Rank, 
noms.Artist, 
noms.Nominations
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(Name) as Nominations, Name as Artist
FROM Nominated
WHERE Year BETWEEN @fromyear AND @toyear
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Nominations DESC
) as noms

) as test

WHERE Rank BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

it returns something like:

```
Rank    Artist              Nominations
1       Michael Jackson     6
2       Lionel Richie       6
// through 5
```

the SQL query works fine on phpMyAdmin. I'm trying to convert this for use with a PHP form. I've gotten this close:

```
<?php

$YEAR1POST=$_POST['YEAR1'];  // user enters YEAR1 and YEAR2
$YEAR2POST=$_POST['YEAR2'];
$Rank = 0;
$ONE = 1;

$sql = "        

SELECT test.Rank, test.Artist, test.Nominations

FROM(


SELECT 
\"$Rank\" =  (  \"$Rank\" + \"$ONE\"  ) AS Rank, 
noms.Artist, 
noms.Nominations

FROM
    (
    SELECT COUNT(Name) as Nominations, Name as Artist
    FROM Nominated
    WHERE Year BETWEEN \"$YEAR1POST\" AND \"$YEAR2POST\"
    GROUP BY Name
    ORDER BY Nominations DESC
    ) as noms

    ) as test

WHERE Rank  = 1

";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$rank = $row['Rank'];
$artist = $row['Artist'];
$nominations = $row['Nominations'];

echo "[Rank:] ". $rank;
echo "<br> [Artist:] ". $artist;
echo "<br> [Nominations:] ". $nominations;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}

 ?>
```

I'm not getting any data when i fetch the result. I'm pretty sure the issue is in:

```
SELECT 
\"$Rank\" =  (  \"$Rank\" + \"$ONE\"  ) AS Rank,
```

I'm just not sure how to convert:

```
SELECT 
@rank:=@rank+1 as Rank,
```

for use with a PHP form. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is not procedural.  Your SQL script is introducing a procedural element with rank, but PHP already is a procedural language.

If you extract just the base query:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT COUNT(Name) as Nominations, Name as Artist
FROM Nominated
WHERE Year BETWEEN '$YEAR1POST' AND '$YEAR2POST'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Nominations DESC";
```

Then you should be returning the same result set, minus the rank.  You can generate the rank in the same way as the SQL client script, by using a PHP variable.

```
$rank = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $artist = $row['Artist'];
    $nominations = $row['Nominations'];

    echo "[Rank:] ". $rank;
    echo "<br> [Artist:] ". $artist;
    echo "<br> [Nominations:] ". $nominations;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    $rank++;
}
```

While perfunctory at this juncture, you really should be using mysqli or PDO now -- the mysql_ api is soon to be removed entirely from PHP.  Those are also much safer in terms of SQL injections and the elimination of the need for string escaping, so long as you use bind variables.

Comment: thanks a lot! i appreciate you directing me towards mysqli or PDO as well. just starting out with SQL/PHP

Comment: No worries, I personally would recommend using PDO/MySQL if I had to choose one.